React Semver security vulnerabilities
Keep receiving the following error message
I've tried almost everything,  installing, reinstalling, manually changing the semver update in the package-lock.json file.
semver  7.0.0 - 7.5.1
Severity: moderate
semver vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-c2qf-rxjj-qqgw
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/@expo/image-utils/node_modules/semver
  @expo/image-utils  <=0.0.1-canary-20240109-93608d8 || >=0.3.10-alpha.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of semver
  node_modules/@expo/image-utils
    @expo/cli  <=0.0.0-canary-20231123-1b19f96-4 || >=0.0.1-canary-20231125-d600e44
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/image-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/prebuild-config
    node_modules/@expo/cli
      expo  50.0.0-alpha.0 - 50.0.14
      Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/cli
      node_modules/expo
    @expo/prebuild-config  *
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/image-utils
    node_modules/@expo/prebuild-config


But have you tried npm audit fix?

I have, it doesn't do anything
